# Detecting background operation

Tags: linux, stdio

In C, what is the way to detect a program was called in "background mode" ?
I have a program I would like to launch either interactively or in background.

How can I detect I should not be reading from stdin and end in a "Stopped : tty input" state ?

Should I test that stdin is closed ? How can I do that ?

Edit :
isatty seems like a good idea, but what happen if stdin is a pipe end, and not a tty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`tcgetpgrp()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetpgrp.html) function on the file descriptor of the controlling terminal (e.g. `STDIN_FILENO` or 0 for stdin) to check whether the current foreground process group is equal to your own process group (from [`getpgrp()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpgrp.html)).  However the foreground process group could change at any time, as your program is moved between foreground and background.  For example, it could change immediately after you call `tcgetpgrp()` and before you test it.  So keep this in mind if you are going to take any action based on this; it is not a reliable method of avoiding `SIGTTIN`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
pid_t fg = tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
if (fg == -1) {
    /* stdin is not controlling terminal (e.g. file, pipe, etc.) */
} else if (fg == getpgrp()) {
    /* foreground */
} else {
    /* background */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should check if stdin is open, and open /dev/null to it if it closed.

2) You can use `isatty` which "returns 1 if desc is an open file descriptor connected to a terminal and 0 otherwise"