# attach a terminal to a process running as a daemon (to run an ncurses UI)

Tags: c, ncurses, pty

I have a (legacy) program which acts as a daemon (in the sense it runs forever waiting for requests to service) but which has an ncurses based user interface which runs on the host.

I would like to alter the program such that if I connect to the host via ssh I can enable the user interface on demand.
I know there is at least one way using pseudo-terminals but I'm not quite sure how to achieve it.
There are two application behaviours I consider interesting:

### Run the UI only if the application is running in the foreground on a terminal

1. If the application runs in the foreground on a terminal - display the UI
2. If the application runs in the background - do not display the UI
3. If the application is moved to the background - close the UI
4. If the application is moved to the foreground of a terminal - open the UI

### Create a new UI on demand when someone connects to the server

1. The application is running in the background
2. A new user logs in to the machine
3. They run something which causes an instance of the UI to open in their terminal
4. Multiple users can have their own instances of the UI.

### Notes

There is a simple way to do this using screen. So:

original:

```
screen mydaemon etc...
```

new ssh session:

```
screen -d     
screen -r
```

This detaches the screen leaving it running in the background and then reattches it to the current terminal. On closing the terminal the screen session becomes detached so this works quite well.

I'd like to understand what screen does under the hood, both for my own education and to understand how you would put some of that functionality into the application itself.

I know how I would do this for a server connected via a socket. What I would like to understand is how this could be done in principle with pseudo terminals. It is indeed a odd way to make an application work but I think it would serve to explore deeply the powers and limitations of using pseudo-terminals.

For case one, I assume I want the ncurses UI running in a slave terminal which the master side passing input to and from it.

The master process would use something like isatty() to check whether it is currently in the foreground of a terminal and activate or deactivate the UI using newterm() and endwin().

I've been experimenting with this but I have not got it to work yet as there are some aspects of terminals and ncurses that I have at best not got to grips with yet and at worst fundamental misunderstand.

Pseudo code for this is:

```
openpty(masterfd,slavefd)
login_tty();  
fork();
ifslave 
  close(stdin)
  close(stdout)
  dup_a_new_stdin_from_slavefd();
  newterm(NULL, newinfd, newoutfd);  (
  printw("hello world");
  insert_uiloop_here();
  endwin();    
else ifmaster
  catchandforwardtoslave(SIGWINCH);
  while(noexit)
  {
     docommswithslave();         
     forward_output_as_appropriate();
  }
```

Typically I either get a [segfault inside fileno_unlocked() in newterm()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65282503/1569204)
or output on the invoking terminal rather than a new invisible terminal.

### Questions

- What is wrong with the above pseudo code?
- Do I have the master and slave ends the right way around?
- What does login_tty actually do here?
- Is there any practical difference between openpty() + login_tty() vs posix_openpt() + grantpt()?
- Does there have to be a running process associated with or slave master tty at all times?

---

Note: This is a different question to [ncurses-newterm-following-openpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282503/ncurses-newterm-following-openpty?noredirect=1&lq=1) which describes a particular incorrect/incomplete implementation for this use case and asks what is wrong with it.

Comment: I have related questions: 

* [Is there a way to connect a shell to a pseudo tty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65152924/1569204)

* [what-can-you-do-with-a-pty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65175134/1569204)

Comment: Note that https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455417/1569204 describes a safer way of detecting foreground/background status using getpgrp() == tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question, and a good example of why we have pseudoterminals.

---

For the daemon to be able to use an ncurses interface, it requires a pseudoterminal (the slave side of a pseudoterminal pair), which is available from the point the daemon starts executing, continuously, until the daemon exits.

For a pseudoterminal to exist, there must be a process that has an open descriptor to the master side of the pseudoterminal pair.  Additionally, it must consume all output from the pseudoterminal slave side (visible stuff output by ncurses).  Usually, a library like vterm is used to interpret that output to "draw" the actual text framebuffer into an array (well, usually two arrays - one for the wide characters displayed in each cell (specific row and clumn), and another for the attributes like color).

For the pseudoterminal pair to work correctly, either the process at the master end is a parent or ancestor of the process running ncurses in the slave end, or the two are completely unrelated.  The process running ncurses in the slave end should be in a new session, with the pseudoterminal as its controlling terminal.  This is easiest to achieve, if we use a small pseudoterminal "server" that launches the daemon in a child process; and indeed, this is the pattern that is typically used with pseudoterminals.

The first scenario is not really feasible, because there is no parent/master process maintaining the pseudoterminal.

We can *provide* the behaviour of the first scenario, by adding a small pseudoterminal-providing "janitor" process, whose task is to maintain the pseudoterminal pair in existence, and to consume any ncurses output generated by the process running in the pseudoterminal pair.

However, that behavour also matches the second scenario.

Put another way, here is what would work:

1. Instead of launching the daemon directly, we use a custom program, say 'janitor', that creates a pseudoterminal and runs the daemon inside that pseudoterminal.
2. Janitor will stay running for as long as the daemon runs.
3. Janitor provides an interface for other processes to "connect" to the master side of the pseudoterminal pair.

   This does not necessarily mean 1:1 proxying of data.  Usually input (keypresses) to the daemon are provided unmodified, but how the contents of the pseudoterminal "framebuffer", the character-based virtual window contents, are transferred does vary.  This is completely under our own control.
4. To connect to the janitor, we'll need a second helper program.

   In the case of 'screen', these two programs are actually the same binary; the behaviour is just controlled by command-line parameters, and keypresses "consumed" by 'screen' itself, to control 'screen' behaviour and not passed to the actual ncurses-based process running in the pseudoterminal.

Thus far, we could just examine [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) or [screen](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/) sources to see how they do the above; it is very straightforward terminal multiplexing stuff.

However, here we have a very interesting bit I had not considered before; this small bit made me understand the quite important core of this question:

> Multiple users can have their own instances of the UI.

A process can only have one controlling terminal.  This specifies a certain relationship.  For example, when the master side of the controlling terminal is closed, the pseudoterminal pair vanishes, and the descriptors open to the slave side of the pseudoterminal pair become nonfunctional (all operations yield EIO, if I recall correctly); but more than that, every process in the process group receives a HUP signal.

The ncurses [newterm()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/newterm.3x.html) function lets a process connect to an existing terminal or pseudoterminal, at run time.  That terminal does not need to be the controlling terminal, nor does the ncurses-using process need to belong to that session.  It is important to realize that in this case, the standard streams (standard input, output, and error) are *not* redirected to the terminal.

So, if there is a way to tell a daemon that it has a new pseudoterminal available, and should open that because there is a user that wants to use the interface the daemon provides, we can have the daemon open and close the pseudoterminals on demand!

Note, however, that this requires explicit co-operation between the daemon, and the processes that are used to connect to the ncurses-based UI the daemon provides. There is no standard way of doing this with arbitrary ncurses-based processes or daemons.  For example, as far as I know, `nano` and `top` provide no such interface; they only use the pseudoterminal associated with the standard streams.

After posting this answer – hopefully fast enough before the question is closed because others do not see the validity of the question, and its usefulness to other server-side POSIXy developers –, I shall construct an example program pair to exemplify the above; probably using an Unix domain socket as the "new UI for this user, please" communications channel, as file descriptors can be passed as ancillary data using Unix domain sockets, and identity of the user at either end of the socket can be verified (credentials ancillary data).

However, for now, let's go back to the questions asked.

> What is wrong with the above pseudo code? [Typically I either get a segfault inside fileno_unlocked() in newterm() or output on the invoking terminal rather than a new invisible terminal.]

`newinfd` and `newoutfd` should be the same (or dup()s of) the pseudoterminal slave end file descriptor, `slavefd`.

I think there should also be an explicit `set_term()` with the SCREEN pointer returned by newterm() as a parameter.  (It could be that it gets automatically called for the very first terminal provided by newterm(), but I'd rather call it explicitly.)

[`newterm()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/newterm.3x.html) connects to and prepares a new terminal.  The two descriptors usually both refer to the same slave side of a pseudoterminal pair; `infd` can be some other descriptor where the user keypresses are received from.

Only one terminal can be active in ncurses at a time.  You need to use [`set_term()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/set_term.3x.html) to select which one will be affected by following `printw()` etc. calls.  (It returns the terminal that was previously active, so that one can do an update to another terminal and then return back to the original terminal.)

(This also means that if a program provides multiple terminals, it must cycle between them, checking for input, and update each terminal, at a relatively high frequency, so that human users feel the UI is responsive, and not "laggy".  A crafty POSIX programmer can select or poll on the underlying descriptors, though, and only cycle through terminals that have input pending.)

> Do I have the master and slave ends the right way around?

Yes, I do believe you do.  Slave end is the one that sees a terminal, and can use ncurses.  Master end is the one that provides keypresses, and does *something* with the ncurses output (say, draws them to a text-based framebuffer, or proxies to a remote terminal).

> What does login_tty actually do here?

There are two commonly used pseudoterminal interfaces: UNIX98 (which is standardized in POSIX), and BSD.

With the POSIX interface, `posix_openpt()` creates a new pseudoterminal pair, and returns the descriptor to its master side.  Closing this descriptor (the last open duplicate) destroys the pair.  In the POSIX model, initially the slave side is "locked", and unopenable.  `unlockpt()` removes this lock, allowing the slave side to be opened.  `grantpt()` updates the character device (corresponding to the slave side of the pseudoterminal pair) ownership and mode to match the current real user.  `unlockpt()` and `grantpt()` can be called in either order, but it makes sense to call `grantpt()` first; that way the slave side cannot be opened "accidentally" by other processes, before its ownership and access mode have been set properly.  POSIX provides the path to the character device corresponding to the slave side of the pseudoterminal pair via `ptsname()`, but Linux provides an [TIOCGPTPEER ioctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) (in kernels 4.13 and later) that allows opening the slave end even if the character device node is not shown in the current mount namespace.

Typically, `grantpt()`, `unlockpt()`, and opening the slave side of the pseudoterminal pair are done in a child process (that still has access to the master-side descriptor) that has started a new session using `setsid()`.  The child process redirects standard streams (standard input, output, and error) to the slave side of the pseudoterminal, closes its copy of the master-side descriptor, and makes sure the pseudoterminal is its controlling terminal.  Usually this is followed by executing the binary that will use the pseudoterminal (usually via ncurses) for its user interface.

With the BSD interface, `openpty()` creates the pseudoterminal pair, providing open file descriptors to both sides, and optionally sets the pseudoterminal termios settings and window size.  It roughly corresponds to POSIX `posix_openpt()` + `grantpt()` + `unlockpt()` + opening the slave side of the pseudoterminal pair + optionally setting the termios settings and terminal window size.

With the BSD interface, `login_tty` is run in the child process.  It runs `setsid()` to create a new session, makes the slave side the controlling terminal, redirects standard streams to the slave side of the controlling terminal, and closes the copy of the master side descriptor.

With the BSD interface, `forkpty()` combines `openpty()`, `fork()`, and `login_tty()`.  It returns twice; once in the parent (returning the PID of the child process), and once in the child (returning zero).  The child is running in a new session, with the pseudoterminal slave side as its controlling terminal, already redirected to the standard streams.

> Is there any practical difference between openpty() + login_tty() vs posix_openpt() + grantpt() [ + unlockpt() + opening the slave side]?

No, not really.

Both Linux and most BSDs tend to provide both.  (In Linux, when using the BSD interface, you need to link in the libutil library (`-lutil` gcc option), but it is provided by the same package that provides the standard C library, and can be assumed to be always available.)

I tend to prefer the POSIX interface, even though it is lots more verbose, but other than kinda preferring POSIX interfaces over BSD ones, I don't even know why I prefer it over the BSD interface. The BSD `forkpty()` does basically everything for the most common use cases in one call!

Also, instead of relying on `ptsname()` (or the GNU ptsname_r() extension), I tend to first try the Linux-specific ioctl if it looks like it is available, and fall back to `ptsname()` if it is not available.  So, if anything, I probably should prefer the BSD interface.. but the `libutil` kinda sorta annoys me a little bit, I guess, so I don't.

I definitely have no objection to others preferring the BSD interface.  If anything, I'm a bit puzzled as to how my preference even exists; normally I prefer the simpler, more robust interfaces over the verbose, complex ones.

> Does there have to be a running process associated with or slave master tty at all times?

There has to be a process having the master side of the pseudoterminal open.  When the last duplicate of the descriptor is closed, the kernel destroys the pair.

Also, if the process having the master side descriptor does not read from it, the process running in the pseudoterminal will unexpectedly block in some ncurses call.  Normally, the calls do not block (or only block for very short durations, shorter than what humans notice).  If the process just reads but discards the input, then we do not actually know the contents of the ncurses terminal!

So, we can say that having a process that reads from the pseudoterminal pair master side, keeping a descriptor open to the master side, is absolutely required.

(The slave side is different; because the character device node is usually visible, a process can close its connection to the pseudoterminal temporarily, and just reopen it later.  In Linux, when no process has an open descriptor to the slave side, the process reading from or writing to the master side will get EIO errors (read() and write() returning -1 with errno==EIO).  I'm not absolutely certain if this is guaranteed behaviour, though; haven't thus far ever relied on it, and only noticed it recently (when implementing an example) myself.

Comment: You can upvote the question if you think its valid. That is a good way to avoid it being closed.

Comment: Did you manage to create an example? I am still struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an ncurses application that animates a bouncing X on each terminal supplied as a parameter:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef   FRAMES_PER_SECOND
#define   FRAMES_PER_SECOND  25
#endif

#define   FRAME_DURATION (1.0 / (double)(FRAMES_PER_SECOND))

/* Because the terminals are not the controlling terminal for this process,
 * this process may not receive the SIGWINCH signal whenever a screen size
 * changes.  Therefore, we call this function to update it whenever we switch
 * between terminals.
*/
extern void _nc_update_screensize(SCREEN *);

/*
 * Signal handler to notice if this program - all its terminals -- should exit.
*/

static volatile sig_atomic_t  done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum)
{
    done = signum;
}

static int install_done(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    return sigaction(signum, &act, NULL);
}

/* Difference in seconds between to timespec structures.
*/
static inline double difftimespec(const struct timespec after, const struct timespec before)
{
    return (double)(after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec)
         + (double)(after.tv_nsec - before.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}

/* Sleep the specified number of seconds using nanosleep().
*/
static inline double nsleep(const double seconds)
{
    if (seconds <= 0.0)
        return 0.0;

    const long  sec = (long)seconds;
    long       nsec = (long)(1000000000.0 * (seconds - (double)sec));
    if (nsec < 0)
        nsec = 0;
    if (nsec > 999999999)
        nsec = 999999999;

    if (sec == 0 && nsec < 1)
        return 0.0;

    struct timespec  req = { .tv_sec = (time_t)sec, .tv_nsec = nsec };
    struct timespec  rem = { .tv_sec = 0,           .tv_nsec = 0    };

    if (nanosleep(&req, &rem) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
        return (double)(rem.tv_sec) + (double)(rem.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;

    return 0.0;
}

/*
 * Structure describing each client (terminal) state.
*/
struct client {
    SCREEN  *term;
    FILE    *in;
    FILE    *out;
    int      col;     /* Ball column */
    int      row;     /* Ball row */
    int      dcol;    /* Ball direction in column axis */
    int      drow;    /* Ball direction in row axis */
};

static size_t          clients_max = 0;
static size_t          clients_num = 0;
static struct client  *clients = NULL;

/* Add a new terminal, based on device path, and optionally terminal type.
*/
static int add_client(const char *ttypath, const char *term)
{
    if (!ttypath || !*ttypath)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    if (clients_num >= clients_max) {
        const size_t   temps_max = (clients_num | 15) + 13;
        struct client *temps;

        temps = realloc(clients, temps_max * sizeof clients[0]);
        if (!temps)
            return errno = ENOMEM;

        clients_max = temps_max;
        clients     = temps;
    }

    clients[clients_num].term = NULL;
    clients[clients_num].in   = NULL;
    clients[clients_num].out  = NULL;
    clients[clients_num].col  = 0;
    clients[clients_num].row  = 0;
    clients[clients_num].dcol = +1;
    clients[clients_num].drow = +1;

    clients[clients_num].in = fopen(ttypath, "r+");
    if (!clients[clients_num].in)
        return errno;

    clients[clients_num].out = fopen(ttypath, "r+");
    if (!clients[clients_num].out) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        fclose(clients[clients_num].in);
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    clients[clients_num].term = newterm(term, clients[clients_num].in,
                                              clients[clients_num].out);
    if (!clients[clients_num].term) {
        fclose(clients[clients_num].out);
        fclose(clients[clients_num].in);
        return errno = ENOMEM;
    }

    set_term(clients[clients_num].term);
    start_color();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    scrollok(stdscr, FALSE);
    curs_set(0);
    clear();
    refresh();

    clients_num++;

    return 0;
}

static void close_all_clients(void)
{
    while (clients_num > 0) {
        clients_num--;

        if (clients[clients_num].term) {
            set_term(clients[clients_num].term);
            endwin();
            delscreen(clients[clients_num].term);
            clients[clients_num].term = NULL;
        }

        if (clients[clients_num].in) {
            fclose(clients[clients_num].in);
            clients[clients_num].in = NULL;
        }

        if (clients[clients_num].out) {
            fclose(clients[clients_num].out);
            clients[clients_num].out = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timespec  curr, prev;
    int              arg;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *arg0 = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", arg0);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s TERMINAL [ TERMINAL ... ]\n", arg0);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program displays a bouncing ball animation in each terminal.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Press Q or . in any terminal, or send this process an INT, HUP,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "QUIT, or TERM signal to quit.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        if (add_client(argv[arg], NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            close_all_clients();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (install_done(SIGINT) == -1 ||
        install_done(SIGHUP) == -1 ||
        install_done(SIGQUIT) == -1 ||
        install_done(SIGTERM) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        close_all_clients();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &curr);
    while (!done && clients_num > 0) {
        size_t  n;

        /* Wait until it is time for the next frame. */
        prev = curr;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &curr);
        nsleep(FRAME_DURATION - difftimespec(curr, prev));

        /* Update each terminal. */
        n = 0;
        while (n < clients_num) {
            int  close_this_terminal = 0;
            int  ch, rows, cols;

            set_term(clients[n].term);

            /* Because the terminal is not our controlling terminal,
               we may miss SIGWINCH window size change signals.
               To work around that, we explicitly check it here. */
            _nc_update_screensize(clients[n].term);

            /* Process inputs - if we get any */
            while ((ch = getch()) != ERR)
                if (ch == 'x' || ch == 'X' || ch == 'h' || ch == 'H')
                    clients[n].dcol = -clients[n].dcol;
                else
                if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y' || ch == 'v' || ch == 'V')
                    clients[n].drow = -clients[n].drow;
                else
                if (ch == '.' || ch == 'q' || ch == 'Q')
                    close_this_terminal = 1;

            if (close_this_terminal) {
                endwin();
                delscreen(clients[n].term);
                fclose(clients[n].in);
                fclose(clients[n].out);
                /* Remove from array. */
                clients_num--;
                clients[n] = clients[clients_num];
                clients[clients_num].term = NULL;
                clients[clients_num].in   = NULL;
                clients[clients_num].out  = NULL;
                continue;
            }

            /* Obtain current terminal size. */
            getmaxyx(stdscr, rows, cols);

            /* Leave a trace of dots. */
            if (clients[n].row >= 0 && clients[n].row < rows &&
                clients[n].col >= 0 && clients[n].col < cols)
                mvaddch(clients[n].row, clients[n].col, '.');

            /* Top edge bounce. */
            if (clients[n].row <= 0) {
                clients[n].row  = 0;
                clients[n].drow = +1;
            }

            /* Left edge bounce. */
            if (clients[n].col <= 0) {
                clients[n].col  = 0;
                clients[n].dcol = +1;
            }

            /* Bottom edge bounce. */
            if (clients[n].row >= rows - 1) {
                clients[n].row  = rows - 1;
                clients[n].drow = -1;
            }

            /* Right edge bounce. */
            if (clients[n].col >= cols - 1) {
                clients[n].col  = cols - 1;
                clients[n].dcol = -1;
            }

            clients[n].row += clients[n].drow;
            clients[n].col += clients[n].dcol;
            mvaddch(clients[n].row, clients[n].col, 'X');
            refresh();

            /* Next terminal. */
            n++;
        }
    }

    close_all_clients();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This contains no pseudoterminals, and the only real quirk is the use of `_nc_update_screensize()` to detect if any of the terminals have changed.  (Because they are not our controlling terminal, we do not receive the SIGWINCH signal, and thus ncurses misses the window change.)

I recommend compiling this with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 bounce.c -lncurses -o bounce`.

Open a couple of terminal windows, and run `tty` to see the path to their controlling terminals (usually slave ends of pseudoterminals, `/dev/pts/N`).
Run `./bounce` with one or more of those paths as parameters, and let the bouncing commence.

If you don't want the shell in a window to consume your input, and want the above program to see it, run e.g. `sleep 6000` in the terminal windows before running the above command.

This program simply opens two streams to each terminal, and lets ncurses take control of them; basically, it is an example of a multi-terminal ncurses application, and how to juggle them using `newterm()`, `set_term()` and so on.

If you supply the same terminal more than once, pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> closes them in a random order, so ncurses may not revert the terminal to the original state correctly.  (You may need to type `reset` blindly, to reset the terminal to a workable state; it's a companion command to `clear`, which just clears the terminal.  They don't do anything else, just terminal stuff.)

Instead of providing the paths to the terminal devices as a command-line parameter, the program could just as well run all the time, but listen for incoming Unix domain datagrams, with SOL_SOCKET-level SCM_RIGHTS-type ancillary data, that can be used to duplicate file descriptors between unrelated processes.

However, if one relinguishes the control of a terminal like that (either by opening the terminal, or by passing the terminal file descriptor to another process), the problem is that it is impossible to revoke that access.  We can avoid that by using a pseudoterminal in between, and proxying the data between the pseudoterminal and our real terminal.  To break the connection, we simply stop proxying data and destroy the pseudoterminal pair, and revert our terminal to its initial state.

Examining the above program, we see that the procedure in pseudocode for taking control of a new terminal is

1. Obtain two FILE stream handles to the terminal.

   The above program uses `fopen()` to open them like normal.  Other programs can use `dup()` to duplicate a single descriptor, and `fdopen()` to convert them to stdio FILE stream handles.
2. Call `SCREEN *term = newterm(NULL, in, out)` to let ncurses know about this new terminal.

   `in` and `out` are the two FILE stream handles.  The first parameter is the terminal type string; if NULL, the TERM environment variable is used instead.  A typical value today is `xterm-256color`, but ncurses supports a lot of other types of terminals also.
3. Call `set_term(term)` to make the new terminal the currently active one.

   At this point, we can do normal ncurses setup stuff, like `cbreak(); noecho();` and so on.

Relinguishing control of a terminal is also simple:

1. Call `set_term(term)` to make that terminal the currently active one.
2. Call `endwin()` and `delscreen(term)`.
3. Close the two FILE streams to the terminal.

Updating terminal contents requires a loop, with each iteration handling one terminal, starting with a `set_term(term)` call (followed by the `_nc_update_screensize(term)` call, if we wish to react to window size changes in those terminals).

The above example program uses `nodelay()` mode, so that `getch()` will return either a keypress, or `ERR` if there is no pending input from the current terminal.  (At least in Linux, we will get `KEY_RESIZE` whenever the window size changes, as long as either the terminal is our controlling terminal, or we call `_nc_update_screensize()`.)

But note: if there are other processes also reading from that terminal, say a shell, the input could be read by any of the processes.

Comment: 1. Are you the same glarbo as in the other answer? your reputations are different?
2. your answer seem unrelated to the question. It uses ncurses but not pseudo-terminal pairs.

Comment: Actually I can tell you are same Glarbo as you have the same identicon.

Comment: I think you are suggesting that this is superior to using pseudo-terminals directly at all. I guess that makes sense as an answer to this question without improving my understanding of pseudo-terminals as required for the other question.

Comment: @BruceAdams: Yes, the same (don't want to register!).  No, this is not superior, this is just how a service can provide multiple concurrent ncurses UIs to users who want one.  (Specific example of point 4 in the second set of targets.) The better option is for the client program the human user uses to connect to the service for the UI to use a pseudoterminal, since then the client program can interrupt the connection (and tear down the pseudoterminal pair) easily.  I am constructing an example of that, and will post it here, it's just that the holidays means I'm busy IRL right now. Patience.

Comment: Merry Christmas. I have the same problem. I would might have worked this all out by now without having the kids climbing all over me 24 hours a day.